# How can I solve this System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception in panel?

Tags: c#

I have a panel that loads 257 user control. When it reached 191 it will return System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

I've red many articles already about solving the exception. I've used GC.Collect() inside and after for loop to release memory because everytime the loop is executed, memory consumption increased. I have also tried .Dispose before and after the loop but none of them worked.

My code is written in C#.

One user control loads 36 controls and the program needed to load more than 191 user controls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run Process Explorer or the Windows Task Manager to look at the **GDI Objects, Handles, Threads and USER objects**? If not, select those columns to be viewed (Task Manager choose View->Select Columns... Then run your app and take a look at those columns for that app and see if one of those is growing really large.

The windows handle limit for an application is 10,000 handles. **It might be that you've got UI components that you think are cleaned up but haven't been Disposed**.

Probably your program is creating too many handles. **You'll need to find the memory leak using a Memory Profile**r. I use the ANTS Memory Profiler. Also, make sure you're calling the Dispose method on controls if you're removing them from a form before the form closes (otherwise the controls won't dispose). You'll also have to make sure that there are no events registered with the control.